# How do I add new language to VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

I am working on adding support for Structured Text language. But I've got lost a little. Where do I contribute? Do I add and extension to VS Code or do I contribute new language in monaco-languages repository?

They have some similar parameters in extension of VS Code and Monaco language definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read these two articles ([1](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server), [2](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/language-support)). Personally, I would go with implementing the [Language Server Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) if at all possible to allow other editors and IDEs to reuse your efforts where possible.

Comment: Thank you. I have created extension for ST but for now without Language Server Protocol. Just some snippets and syntax highlights.